# jquery slider navbar conflict

Tags: jquery, html

after adding a slider my jQuery nav bar ceases to work...I am very new to HTML & jQuery so any help will be gratefully received.

http://www.trianglecircustest.webspace.virginmedia.com/index.html

nav bar is...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            /**
            * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
            * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
            * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
            * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
            * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
            */
            $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                $elem.find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'170px',
                        'height':'100px',
                        'left':'0px'
                     },400,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'100px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'100px'},300,function(){
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length){
                        var left = '170px';
                        if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                            left = '-170px';
                        $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
                    }   
                });
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                if($sub_menu.length)
                    $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

                $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                     .andSelf().find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'0px',
                        'height':'0px',
                        'left':'85px'},400)
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'20px'},500);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

slider is...

```
enter code here

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<!-- SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready -->
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 700,
    height: 300,
    navigation: {
    active: true,
      effect: "fade"
    },
    play: {
    auto: "true"
    },
    pagination: {
      effect: "fade"
    },
    effect: {
      fade: {
        speed: 400
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your easing call is incorrect, firebug: **TypeError: x.easing[this.easing] is not a function**. Try adding this library to the head instead of the middle of the document.

Comment: Side note, use `background-position:fixed` on the body background, it'll look much better (:

Comment: thank you for the help the nav bar is now working but I seem to have lost all interaction with the right side of the page ie the twitter feed can not be scrolled...have I missed something obvious there?